# How to use constructor property promotion with extend class?

Tags: magento2, php-8

Can someone please tell me is it possible to use "constructor property promotion" with an extended child class?

Please see the below constructor; it's having a parent class. Can we use "constructor property promotion" for this constructor?

```
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager, 
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
    }
```

Regards